# Missing folder from Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Today while running our mobile app. Suddenly saw that all images failed to load. Logged in using FTP to the Azure Web App running the API and discovered that the `Uploads` folder we have set up where all uploads are stored went missing.

I am checking the logs but cannot determine what caused this. Nothing seems to point to this particular event.

I would like to know if there is a way to restore that deleted folder (maybe some sort of a Recycle Bin type of thing, if that exists).

NB: I am not running on a plan that supports daily backups for the Web App.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update**
I tried to contact support with a case level of Sv 1; as they claim response < 1 hour. Still did not hear anything from them.. Apparently worst support ever.

Comment: Where was the uploads folder located?

Comment: site/wwwroot/Uploads

Comment: well, that should be persistent. Maybe you performed a deployment that cleaned the wwwroot?

Comment: There were no deployments in the log, I tried to check if this happened but I was unable to find anything. (I have a deploy event that was initiated by a null value (no email can be seen))

Comment: Hm, try to download the deployment logs here and check them: `https://<YOURAPP>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/dump` Btw, any reason for not using a blob storage? :-)

Comment: Appreciate the help Martin, actually it's user 'antares'... Any specific file I should be looking at? And is there any possibility of restoring the file even if I find out what happened in the logs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166424/discussion-between-martin-brandl-and-user1027620).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are deleted, I doubt there is a way to restore them (you could ask the support). You should check whether there was a deployment (which could wipe the wwwroot) by downloading the deployment logs using:

```
https://<YOURAPP>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/dump
```

To check whether the files exists anywhere on your app service you could connect to the kudu powershell console environment using the following link:

```
https://<YOURAPP>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell
```

Then switch to `D:\` and use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to find your files. e. g.:

```
Get-ChildItem '*.png' -recurse
```